# Two views within a view, top with button and the lower not showing the firebase data

Tags: swiftui

Simple project to be able to understand the concept.

I have two views UpperView and LowerView. The UpperView has a button, when clicked the button calls a ViewModel that fetches data from firebase. My problem is displaying the fetched data in the LowerView. I initialize the ViewModel in the LowerView so that I can access the fetched data through a @Published property but it doesn't work. It's a pretty simple case that I have built in order to understand the concept. Here is the code for UpperView, LowerView and the ViewModel. HomeView is the combination of the UpperView and the LowerView. It feels as if the data is loaded after the LowerView is displayed. All help will be appreciated!!

```
import Foundation


class MergeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var clients: [Client] = [Client]()
    
    func fetchAllClients() {
        COLLECTION_CLIENTS.getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.clients = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Client.self)})
            print(self.clients.count)
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct UpperView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MergeViewModel()
    @State var numberOfClients: Int = 0
    @State var buttonPressed: Int = 0
    @State var clients: [Client] = [Client]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.red)
            VStack{
                
                Text("This is UPPER VIEW ")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("We have \(numberOfClients) of clients!")
                Text("Button pressed \(buttonPressed)")
                
                Button(action: {
                        viewModel.fetchAllClients()
                        numberOfClients = viewModel.clients.count
                        buttonPressed += 1
                }, label: {
                    Text("Press")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.50))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
            }
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct UpperView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UpperView()
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct LowerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MergeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("This is LOWER VIEW")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Text("\(viewModel.clients.count)")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            List(viewModel.clients) { client in
                Text(client.clientName)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LowerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LowerView()
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                UpperView()
               
                LowerView()
               
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
         
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("logo_silueta")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 30)
                        Text("TheJump")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.8))
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        AuthViewModel.shared.signOut()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("logout")
                        
                    })
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It will never work with that code because each view is creating its own view model, so each view will read from a different `clients` variable. You should create the view model in the `HomeView` and share it with the other views, either as a `Binding` or injecting the view model in the Environment from `HomeView` and reading it in `UpperView` + `LowerView` as an `EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: Every time you call `MergeViewModel()` you create a different instance, one does not know about the other. Use `@StateObject` as the top/source of truth and use `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` for passing around don't call `MergeViewModel()` several times. Also, `@State` is a source of truth and `@Binding` is a two way connection, don't create copies of your array for different sources of truth

Comment: Genius and greatly explained, thank you @HunterLion. I will update my code to show how it works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input!

Here is how it works correctly:

###### ViewModel

```
import Foundation


class MergeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var clients: [Client] = [Client]()
    
    init(){
        fetchAllClients()
    }
    
    func fetchAllClients() {
        COLLECTION_CLIENTS.getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.clients = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Client.self)})
            print(self.clients.count)
        }
    }
}
```

###### UpperView

```
import SwiftUI

struct UpperView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MergeViewModel
    @State var numberOfClients: Int = 0
    @State var buttonPressed: Int = 0
    @State var clients: [Client] = [Client]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.red)
            VStack{
                
                Text("This is UPPER VIEW ")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("We have \(numberOfClients) of clients!")
                Text("Button pressed \(buttonPressed)")
                
                Button(action: {
                        viewModel.fetchAllClients()
                        numberOfClients = viewModel.clients.count
                        buttonPressed += 1
                }, label: {
                    Text("Press")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.50))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
            }
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct UpperView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UpperView(viewModel: MergeViewModel())
    }
}
```

###### LowerView

```
struct LowerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MergeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("This is LOWER VIEW")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Text("\(viewModel.clients.count)")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            List(viewModel.clients) { client in
                Text(client.clientName)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LowerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LowerView(viewModel: MergeViewModel())
    }
}
```